# Python Dataframe get max Value from max Date

Tags: python, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have the following df:

```
    Date         Email              Amount
0   2020-04-09   john@xxmail.com    10
1   2020-05-09   john@xxmail.com    30
2   2020-08-20   mary@xxmail.com    40
3   2020-09-20   mary@xxmail.com    20
4   2020-05-04   nick@xxmail.com    10
5   2020-06-04   nick@xxmail.com    10
6   2020-07-04   nick@xxmail.com    10
7   2020-07-04   nick@xxmail.com    125
```

What i need is to get the max Date for each Email, and then out of these Dates/Email i want the max Amount.

So an intermediate step would be like this for the max Date:

```
    Date         Email              Amount
0   2020-05-09   john@xxmail.com    30
1   2020-09-20   mary@xxmail.com    20
2   2020-07-04   nick@xxmail.com    10
3   2020-07-04   nick@xxmail.com    125
```

And finally we get this for max Amount:

```
    Date         Email              Amount
0   2020-05-09   john@xxmail.com    30     # general max date and max amount
1   2020-09-20   mary@xxmail.com    20     # not general max amount
2   2020-07-04   nick@xxmail.com    125    # max amount of max date
```

To me seems like a double groupby, but i'm not sure.

Clarifications:

- An Email may have more than one row with max Date.
- The max Amount of the max Date may not be the max Amount generally for one email

Answer (score 0):

The dates and quantities are grouped separately and combined in aggregate.

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df_d = df.groupby('Email')['Date'].agg(max).reset_index()
df_a = df.groupby('Email')['Amount'].agg(max).reset_index()
final = pd.concat([df_d,df_a],axis=1)
final.columns = ['Date', 'Email', 'Email1', 'Amount']
final = final[['Date', 'Email', 'Amount']]
final
Date    Email   Amount
0   2020-05-09  john@xxmail.com 30
1   2020-09-20  mary@xxmail.com 40
2   2020-07-04  nick@xxmail.com 125
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! it's pretty close, but i need the max Amount of the max Date, not max Date and max Amount generally. maybe it wasn't clear enough in the description. i'll change it.

Comment: I overlooked the requirements. The code has been updated.

Comment: i made more clarifications so that we get on the same page

Comment: I understand the updated content, but there is a lack of requirement as to which one, for example, if there are two identical emails on the same day.

Comment: the Email is the main "key". if one Email has two+ rows with the same Date, and this Date is the max Date for that Email, then we keep the one with max Amount between them, without caring for the Amount of previous Dates.